# git error "Please tell me who you are." and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I was working in `branch master`, and committing to Git repository. Everything worked fine. I connected new app to this repository on Heroku.

I was committing to both Heroku and Git. Everything worked fine again (except I cannot run db:migrate on Heroku but that is another question...). After my last commit I run `git status` and received: `On branch master. Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.`

Today I made some changes in my code, but suddenly I cannot commit - received error "Please tell me who you are." The only difference from previous commits is that had a migration, if it is of any importance. 
When I run `git config --global --get user.email`command I get an empty line in return.

Why have I suddenly lost connection to git?

Comment: `git config --global` is just for view global settings on a LOCAL pc. show please `cat ~/.gitconfig |grep email` also with `cat .git/config |grep email`

Comment: INB:club_admin irena$ cat ~/.gitconfig |grep email
 email = 
INB:club_admin irena$ cat .git/config |grep email
INB:club_admin irena$

Comment: try remove email section from local git config, and retry login to heroku

Comment: i was trying to commit to github before i change to another branch. I need to commit to github first

Comment: no, `.git/config` is system git folder, it isnt and shouldnt be controlled by a git for current tree

Comment: to be honest I do not know how to do that: try remove email section from local git config. I do not understand why i cannot commit to github now? what has changed???

Comment: for example with console editor like `vim`: `vim .git/config`, and then edit, or by any other editor

Comment: well I saw now what you have no email section in local git config

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99251/discussion-between-clonecq-and--).

Comment: what is the record for email ` INB:club_admin` in global admin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your `email`, and `name` parameters in global config are empty. Probably you have executed something like this, that has dropped the values:

```
git config --global user.name ""
git config --global user.email ""
```

Just fill them with commands again:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "your@email.com"
```

Where `your@email.com` is your github email.

**NOTE:** You can push out of hand to heroku, bypassing the github, since heroku also have git repo itself.

Comment: as Малъ Скрылевъ suggested, I run git config --global user.email user@example.com (my github email) and i was able to push to github again!

Comment: @clonecq You can push out of hand to heroku, bypassing the github, since heroku also have git repo itself.

Comment: I solved my problem, but would like to find out why this happened. I run **git log** and noticed my email was irena@INB.local, and now it is set to my normal email address. why I had @INB.local all this time (I have been committing this project for nearly a year)?