# Git Github.com HTML

Tags: git, github

I recently started HTML,CSS AND JAVASCRIPT course on Coursera.com..
I am facing some errors. I hope you people can help me out..

Whenever I use the `git commit -m "WHATEVER"` command I get a error like this..

```
C:\Windows\System32\coursetest>git commit -m "Page"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity. Omit `--global` to set the
identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Shantanu
Bhadouria@DESKTOP-VR557ID.(none)')

C:\Windows\System32\coursetest\site>git commit -c "Page" fatal: could
not lookup commit Page
```

Please Help...

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git error "Please tell me who you are." and Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517434/git-error-please-tell-me-who-you-are-and-heroku)

Comment: This should be one of the first things covered in every Git tutorial. The error message is also telling you what to run to fix this error.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal don't worry, You have to set `username` and `email` after **First-Time Git Setup**. See here for more https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

**From DOC:**

> The first thing you should do when you install Git is to set your user
>   name and email address. This is important because every Git commit
>   uses this information, and it’s immutably baked into the commits you
>   start creating:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your name goes here"
$ git config --global user.email "Your_email_address_goes_here"
```

To verify what settings you set,

```
git config --list
```