# git-simple : fatal: unable to auto-detect email address

Tags: node.js, git

I'm trying to commit using the package **"git-simple"**.

The idea is to authenticate using the token provided by github api, create remote repository, create the .gitignore and then setup files.

Here is my code to run the script

```
const run = async () => {
try {
// Retrieve & Set Authentication Token
const token = await getGithubToken();
github.githubAuth(token);

// Create remote repository
const url = await repo.createRemoteRepo();

// Create .gitignore file
await repo.createGitignore();

// Setup local repository and push to remote
const done = await repo.setupRepo(url);

if(done) {
  console.log(chalk.green('All done!'));
}
} catch(err) {
  if (err) {
    switch (err.code) {
      case 401:
        console.log(chalk.red('Couldn\'t log you in. Please provide correct credentials/token.'));
        break;
      case 422:
        console.log(chalk.red('There already exists a remote repository with the same name'));
        break;
      default:
        console.log(err);
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Everything is okey until the execution **repo.setupRepo(url)**

Here the code for setupRepo(url)

```
    setupRepo : async(url) =>{
    const status = new Spinner('Initializing local repository and pushing to remote...')
    status.start()

    try{
        await git
            .init()
            .add('.gitignore')
            .add('./*')
            .commit('initial commit')
            .addRemote('origin',url)
            .push('origin','master')
        return true
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    finally{
        status.stop()
    }
}
```

I got this message :

```
 Git#then is deprecated after version 1.72 and will be removed in version 2.x
 Please switch to using Git#exec to run arbitrary functions as part of the 
 command chain.

 / Initializing local repository and pushing to remote...
 *** Please tell me who you are.

 Run

 git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
 git config --global user.name "Your Name"

 to set your account's default identity.
 Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

 fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Anes@DESKTOP-E9U575A.
(none)')

| Initializing local repository and pushing to remote...
```

When I open my github account, I found that the repository is already created but it's empty.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git error "Please tell me who you are." and Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517434/git-error-please-tell-me-who-you-are-and-heroku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problem too.

#### how to solve?

see the code below,change ssh_url to clone_url.

```
    createRemoteRepo: async () => {
    const github = gh.getInstance();
    const answers = await inquirer.askRepoDetails();

    const data = {
        name: answers.name,
        description: answers.description,
        private: (answers.visibility === 'private')
    };

    const status = new Spinner('Creating remote repository...');
    status.start();

    try {
        const response = await github.repos.create(data);
        // return response.data.ssh_url;
        return response.data.clone_url;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    } finally {
        status.stop();
    }
}
```

detail response see here [create repo](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create)

#### Why?

Difference between: SSH and https。[Which remote URL should I use?](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/)

Other solutions, but I didn't experiment.

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```